# Inkscape 0.91 Freehand shape issues

Tags: inkscape

I was watching a tutorial where a gentleman using an older version of Inkscape was able to draw freehand lands with the triangle in shape, therefore making the lines thin at the end of the shape and thick at the beginning (where he started drawing).

Trying to follow in Inkscape 0.91 I ran into the issue where it by default drew a thin line. I tried to make it thicker by changing the width in Path Effects but that had no effect (on that shape or any I drew after). I could change the width by increasing the width of the stroke, but then I lost my "triangle" shape (the whole freehand shape was pretty much had the same line width).

So how do I get the triangle in freehand drawing to work in the new version of Inkscape? Thank you!

Comment: After selecting the freehand tool, there's a "Shape" drop down in the top toolbar. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I selected the shape and selected "triangle in" so I did that correctly, oddly though I'm still having issues and I cannot get what I'm trying to do (Which is modify the width of the "triangle in" freehand shape. There has to be a way to do it I shouldn't have to download a legacy Inkscape build just for certain shapes -_-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In inkscape 0.91 the effect for the "triangle in" shape is obtained with the "power stroke".

Select draw freehand (F6), select "triangle in" shape and draw a line (set the smoothing to 40 or more for best result);
to change the width of the shape: press F2 (edit path), you'll see a small pink square (is the control for the "Power stroke"): drag this square for change the width; CTRL+click add a new control point; CTRL+ALT+click delete a control square.

If in your version the effect is "Pattern along path" you can change the shape by selecting the first icon after "Pattern source" in the path effect dialog (the node editing icon): you can edit the temporary green copy of the pattern.